# how can i interpolate the data to reduce the coordinate to few numbers without changing the shape of original data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a file that contains 250 coordinates. Now how can I interpolate the data to reduce the coordinates to a few numbers say suppose to 100 without changing the shape of the original data graph?
Below are the example coordinates...

```
3.69014,-0.0527779
3.70677,-0.0481951
3.72343,-0.043741
3.74013,-0.0391163
3.75687,-0.0341463
3.77366,-0.0290773
3.7905,-0.0240456
3.80741,-0.0186694
3.82439,-0.0129752
3.84145,-0.00727358
3.8586,-0.00148542
3.87584,0.0047693
3.89318,0.0113316
3.91062,0.0178894
3.92818,0.0246717
3.92818,0.0246717
3.94587,0.0319402
3.96368,0.0395285
3.98164,0.0472058
3.99974,0.0551477
4.018,0.0636555
4.03642,0.0725895
4.05502,0.0814367
4.07381,0.0897025
4.0928,0.0963327
4.112,0.103078
4.13143,0.990615
```

I have a script which I used to interpolate but it chooses the coordinates randomly and eliminates them..
data[] represents the slope between two consecutive coordinates, and the slope diff[] represents the difference between two consecutive slopes. Below I provided a small part of the code of how I did...

```
del_points_index = []
        data_new = data.copy()
        for i in range(data.shape[0]-POINTS_NUMBER):
            del_point = slope_dif_df[0].idxmin()+1
            del_points_index.append(del_point)
            slope_dif_df.drop(del_point-1, inplace=True)
            data_new.drop(index=del_point, inplace=True)
```

Below I am attaching the graph[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyAID.jpg) and graph[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xXHU.jpg)....

U can see the rounded coordinates where there are cluster of points, if I gave to delete 100 coordinates it does, but if I gave 130 coordinates to delete, instead of choosing the coordinates from the cluster, it deletes the coordinates where there are only a few, by this graph shape changes.

Is there any alternative...

This is my whole script...

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
POINTS_NUMBER = 100 #how many coordinates to keep
def calculate_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
    return slope
folder = r"defining the path"
files = os.listdir(folder)
plots_folder = os.path.join(folder, "Plots")
os.makedirs(plots_folder, exist_ok=True)

for file in files:
    if file.endswith('.dat'):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, file)
        data = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
        data = data.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
        slopes = []
        x_values = data.iloc[:, 0]
        y_values = data.iloc[:, 1]
        for i in range(len(x_values)-1):
            x1, y1 = x_values.iloc[i], y_values.iloc[i]
            x2, y2 = x_values.iloc[i + 1], y_values.iloc[i + 1]
            slope = calculate_slope(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            slopes.append(slope)
        differences = [abs(((slopes[i + 1] - slopes[i]) / slopes[i])*100) 
for i in range(len(slopes) - 1)]
        slope_dif_df = pd.DataFrame(differences)
        del_points_index = []
        data_new = data.copy()
        for i in range(data.shape[0]-POINTS_NUMBER):
            del_point = slope_dif_df[0].idxmin()+1
            del_points_index.append(del_point)
            slope_dif_df.drop(del_point-1, inplace=True)
            data_new.drop(index=del_point, inplace=True)
        file_basename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        plt.plot(data.iloc[:,0], data.iloc[:,1])
        plt.scatter(data.iloc[:, 0], data.iloc[:, 1], c='b', label='b = original data')
        plt.plot(data_new.iloc[:,0], data_new.iloc[:,1])
        plt.scatter(data_new.iloc[:, 0], data_new.iloc[:, 1], c='r', label='r = reduced data')
        plt.xlabel()
        plt.ylabel()
        plt.legend()
        plot_path = os.path.join(plots_folder, f"{file_basename}_plot.png")
        plt.savefig(plot_path)
        plt.clf()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see what you are trying to do. Please also format the data in a readable way. Note: Stack Overflow is not a code request site. We expect you to try and solve the problem and search on the site and elsewhere for solutions before posting a question. Interpolation is extremely common so there are many questions and examples on the topic.

Comment: the question that you ask contradicts itself. If the data is reduced, then the shape will have changed (reduced)...

Comment: `I have a script which I used to interpolate but it chooses the coordinates randomly and eliminates them` Can we see the code you're using for this now?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example that uses clustering to determine the best points to drop. You need to set `n_to_drop`. You may also need to tune `n_clusters=` to tweak performance. I tried this out on a synthetic dataset.

It uses KMeans clustering and then scores each sample by how well-clustered it is (silhouette score). After some brief experimentation, it seemed like samples that score low tend to be further apart and less dense (flat lines), whereas samples that score high tend to be in a more dense area (curves). This provides a metric for preferentially dropping the least important points.

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create some test data
original_t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
original_y = np.cos(original_t * 0.9) * np.sin(2 * original_t)

#Plot test data
f, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10, 6))
axs[0].plot(original_t, original_y,
            linestyle='none', marker='|',
            markersize=30, label='original y')

#Cluster the data in time-value space
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#You will need to tune how many clusters to use
n_clusters = 50

original_t_and_y = np.stack([original_t, original_y], axis=1)
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters, n_init='auto').fit(original_t_and_y)

#Score each sample by how well-clustered it is.
# Samples that score low tend to be further
# apart and less dense (flat lines), whereas
# samples that score high tend to be in a more dense area (curves)
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples
silhouette_scores = silhouette_samples(original_t_and_y, kmeans.labels_)
#Mark edge points as important - they're required for good interpolation at edges.
silhouette_scores[[0, -1]] = silhouette_scores.max()

#Get indices sorted by score - low scoring to high
sorted_idxs = np.argsort(silhouette_scores)

#You can visualise how well-clustered each sample is:
im = axs[1].scatter(original_t, original_y, c=silhouette_scores, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar(im)
axs[1].set_title('Importance scores')

#Select how many to drop
n_to_drop = 30

#Drop the lowest-scoring bunch (usually means the most spread-out points)
reduced_idxs = sorted_idxs[n_to_drop:]
reduced_idxs.sort()

#Create the reduced dataset
reduced_t = original_t[reduced_idxs]
reduced_y = original_y[reduced_idxs]

#Plot the points we are keeping
axs[0].scatter(reduced_t, reduced_y, c='blue',
               s=30, label=f'kept (after dropping {n_to_drop} other points)')

#Interpolate the reduced data onto the original axis
interp_reduced_y = np.interp(original_t, reduced_t, reduced_y)
axs[0].plot(original_t, interp_reduced_y, color='r', linestyle='-',
            linewidth=2, label='interpolation of the reduced dataset')

f.legend(loc='upper left')
```

Comment: Updated to improve interpolation at the edges.